# Fill a struct which contains slices

Tags: go

I am trying to glean the basics of Go.

I am trying to render a template in golang with prefilled value for a struct. But no luck

```
func ServeIndex(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    p := &Page{
        Title:   " Go Project CMS",
        Content: "Welcome to our home page",
        Posts: []*Post{
            &Post{
                Title:         "Hello World",
                Content:       "Hello, World Thanks for coming to this site",
                DatePublished: time.Now(),
            },
            &Post{
                Title:         "A Post with comments",
                Content:       "Here is the controversial post",
                DatePublished: time.Now(),
                Comments: []*Comment{
                    &Comment{
                        Author:        "Sathish",
                        Comment:       "Nevermind, I guess",
                        DatePublished: time.Now().Add(-time.Hour / 2),
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }

    Tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "page", p)
}
```

Here is my struct definition

```
import (
    "html/template"
    "time"
)

// Tmpl is exported and can be used by other packages
var Tmpl = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("../templates/*"))

type Page struct {
    Title   string
    Content string
    Posts   *[]Post
}

type Post struct {
    Title         string
    Content       string
    DatePublished time.Time
    Comments      *[]Comment
}

type Comment struct {
    Author        string
    Comment       string
    DatePublished time.Time
}
```

When i tried to run this code via main.go file, i am getting following error

```
../handler.go:60: cannot use []*Comment literal (type []*Comment) as type *[]Comment in field value
../handler.go:62: cannot use []*Post literal (type []*Post) as type *[]Post in field value
```

Can you help me understand what actually a problem is? I was following a video tutorial.

EDIT: Updated the code based on the mktopriva suggestions

```
func ServeIndex(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    p := &Page{
        Title:   " Go Project CMS",
        Content: "Welcome to our home page",
        Posts: *[]Post{
            &Post{
                Title:         "Hello World",
                Content:       "Hello, World Thanks for coming to this site",
                DatePublished: time.Now(),
            },
            &Post{
                Title:         "A Post with comments",
                Content:       "Here is the controversial post",
                DatePublished: time.Now(),
                Comments: *[]Comment{
                    &Comment{
                        Author:        "Sathish",
                        Comment:       "Nevermind, I guess",
                        DatePublished: time.Now().Add(-time.Hour / 2),
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }

    Tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "page", p)
}
```

Got below errors

```
../handler.go:45: cannot use Post literal (type *Post) as type Post in array or slice literal
../handler.go:50: cannot use *Post literal (type *Post) as type Post in array or slice literal
../handler.go:55: cannot use Comment literal (type *Comment) as type Comment in array or slice literal
../handler.go:60: invalid indirect of []Comment literal (type []Comment)
../handler.go:62: invalid indirect of []Post literal (type []Post)
```

Comment: You declared the field types as *pointers-to-slices*, but you are providing values of type *slice-of-pointers*. Don't use pointers-to-slices here, they are sometimes useful but not here. Change `Comments      *[]Comment` to  `Comments      []*Comment` and the other ones as well.

Comment: @mkopriva i am getting below error now - ../handler.go:45: cannot use Post literal (type *Post) as type Post in array or slice literal
../handler.go:50: cannot use *Post literal (type *Post) as type Post in array or slice literal
../handler.go:55: cannot use Comment literal (type *Comment) as type Comment in array or slice literal
../handler.go:60: invalid indirect of []Comment literal (type []Comment)
../handler.go:62: invalid indirect of []Post literal (type []Post)

Comment: `*[]Post{...` is invalid Go. Use the address operator if you want to initialize a pointer to a slice. e.g. `&[]Post`.

Comment: can you please post the corrected code in answer @mkopriva that way i can upvote ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mkopriva is correct, but I'd guess that this isn't what you wanted...

Your struct declaration is slightly off, for example, Page has `a pointer to a slice of Post values`, you probably wanted `a slice of Post pointers` as that would be generally how people use slices.  Your declaration just needs the `*` put next to the type, rather than the `[]` and then your creation code will work.

```
import (
    "html/template"
    "time"
)

// Tmpl is exported and can be used by other packages
var Tmpl = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("../templates/*"))

type Page struct {
    Title   string
    Content string
    Posts   []*Post
}

type Post struct {
    Title         string
    Content       string
    DatePublished time.Time
    Comments      []*Comment
}

type Comment struct {
    Author        string
    Comment       string
    DatePublished time.Time
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared some of the field types as *pointers-to-slices*, but you are providing to them values of type *slice-of-pointers*.

For example, given the field `Comments *[]Comment`, you would initialize its value like so:

```
Comments: &[]Comment{},
```

See here for more alternatives: https://play.golang.org/p/l9HQEGxE5MP

---

Also in slices, arrays, and maps if the element type is known, i.e. it is not an interface, you can omit type from the initialization of the elements and just use curly braces, so code like this:

```
[]*Post{&Post{ ... }, &Post{ ... }}
```

can be changed to:

```
[]*Post{{ ... }, { ... }}
```